# defined a std::list but get error on iterator

Tags: c++, list

I have defined a `std::list` but I don't know why I can not use iterators

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
class foo {
public:
  static const int N = 10;
  list<int *> myList[ N ];
  void bar()
  {
     list<int *>::iterator it = myList.begin();   //ERROR
  }
};

int main()
{
  foo a;
  a.bar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: myList is an array, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have an array of lists, and not a list. Shouldn't

```
list<int *> myList[N];
```

really be

```
list<int *> myList;
```

?

Comment: I did that to bound the the size while I want to use list functions such as push_back(), ....

Comment: @mahmood But that's not how you do that.

Comment: a simple bounded std::list for a given size

Comment: @mahmood You can always check `if (list.size() > SOME_MAX_SIZE)` and insert only if it isn't.